# JFrog Artifactory: using "Remember Me" login feature causes login to fail

Tags: artifactory

I am using JFrog Artifactory 7.5.7 installed on CentOS 7.
I am facing an issue with "Remember Me" feature on the login page, when I select it the login fails and I get the following error on the UI:

```
500 Server Error

An unexpected error has occurred and your request could not be completed.Please try again and in case this problem persists contact your system administrator.
```

From the browser's Developer Tools > Network trace I see the following request is failing:

```
Request URL:https:// Server Name /ui/api/v1/ui/auth/login?_spring_security_remember_me=true

Request Method:POST

Remote Address:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Status Code:502
```

I can see that request in few different Artifactory logs, but no hints so as to why it fails.

Do you have any tips how to further troubleshoot that issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Artifactory log file?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing on 7.5.7

Chrome debug:

> Request URL:
> https://INTERNAL_HOSTNAME/ui/api/v1/ui/auth/login?_spring_security_remember_me=true
> Request Method: POST Status Code: 502  Remote Address:
> INTERNAL_IP:443 Referrer Policy: no-referrer

Relevant log entry:

> 2020-07-10T04:31:56.696Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [4db58a22a87c78cb]
> [j.a.s.s.t.TokenServiceImpl:405] [27.0.0.1-8040-exec-6] - Deleted 1
> tokens with user: 'noe.gonzalez' and scope
> 'authentication:remember-me'.

Seems like the token/session is getting revoked even when checking the "remember me" box on homepage.

Comment: Hi Noe, i can see same entry appearing in access-request.log. Have you found any workaround or fix for that issue?

Comment: work around is to not click the "remember me" box on the homepage :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed after upgrading the artifactory to 7.6.3

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Artifactory 7.5.8 too. Getting this event logged in the console.log - [j.a.s.s.t.TokenServiceImpl:405] [7.0.0.1-8040-exec-10] - Deleted 1 tokens with user: '' and scope 'authentication:remember-me'.

Tried this in Incognito in FF, but it still throws the same error. The UI shows '500 Server Error' where as the web console says its a '502 Bad Gateway' from the Nginx server.

Unchecking 'remember me' checkbox when logging in is the way around.